# Why does calling logout() in middleware not work for the current request?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-middleware, django-sessions

I've built a small custom middleware to log out the user and flush the session conditionally. I'd expect the current request to have the user logged out. However, for the request/response currently being processed, I still have a full response as if the user hadn't been logged out and the session is perfectly available (unexpected). All subsequent request don't have the session anymore (as expected).

Digging down in the `SessionStore` it appears that the session is just a model and is restored further in the request just by the session key from the cookie the browser has sent. Additionally, the `logout()` seems to be ineffective because of that too.

How can I actually log out a user in the middleware? Do I have to manually delete the session from the database? That seems so painful.

In `myapp/middleware.py`:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware
from django.contrib.auth import logout

class SomeSessionMiddleware(SessionMiddleware):

def process_response(self, request, response):
    if somecondition:
        logout(request)
        request.session.flush()
        print "flushing session, log out user" # I see this.
    # And just call the super class
    return super(SomeSessionMiddleware, self).process_response(request, response)
```

In `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'myapp.middleware.SomeSessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Page is already rendered there

Using `process_response`, this is called very late in rendering the *response*.  I need to use `process_request` instead to perform this. Additionally, note that the middlewares defined are called in reverse order for the response.

This will work:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.middleware import SessionMiddleware

class SomeSessionMiddleware(SessionMiddleware):
def process_request(self, request):
    if somecondition:
        request.session.flush()
```